# Profile delete folder if a subfolder exists and contains files older than a certain date

Tags: powershell

I've dug around but have yet to come across something that is nudging me in the right direction regarding a script that will do the following:

```
   -enumerate over a folder of profiles
   -check a one level down to see if a certain subfolder exists    
   -if it exist
          -check last modified date 
              -if older than jan 1, 2015, delete files AND the folder 
                  -write the user's profile name and files deleted to a log file
              -if not older than jan 1, 2015, do not delete
                  -write the user's profile name to a log file
```

File structure looks like this

```
-profiles
    -name1
        -folder1
             -folder2
                 fileOlderThanXDate.old
    -name2
        -folder1
            -folder2
                fileNewerthanXdate.new
    -name3
        -folder1
```

So, within profiles, search down into name 1, then into folder 1 [which everyone will have], if there is a folder2, check lastModifiedDate of the files within, if old, delete the file, AND folder2, then write name1 and those files to a log. 
Continue to name2, seems folder2 in folder1, but the file is newer, then just write name2 to a different log.
Continue to name2, no folder 2 in folder 1, continue

Im finding all hints and pieces to folder a folder and delete, to find a file if older than x days, delete, but nothing that i can put the pieces of the puzzle together.  This is a bear of a question, but appreciate any push in any direction...otherwise, it will be LOTS of clicking and deleting for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a simple ForEach loop and the Test-Path cmdlet (assuming PSv3 or higher). I also use Split-Path for output purposes to the logs.

```
Switch(Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Directory|Select -Expand FullName){
    {!(Test-Path $_\Folder1\Folder2)}{Continue}
    {Test-Path $_\Folder1\Folder2\* -OlderThan "10/01/2014 12:00 AM"}{Split-Path $_ -Leaf|Out-File Old.txt -Append;Remove-Item $_\Folder1\Folder2 -Recurse -Force;continue}
    default {Split-Path $_ -leaf | Out-File NotOld.txt -Append}
}
```

**Edit:** I added `\*` to the end of the path on the second switch condition, so it'll look at the files within Folder2 instead of looking at Folder2 for the date modified. Now it'll look to see if any files within the folder are old, and if they are delete the whole folder and output the name to the Old.txt log file.

Comment: TY TheMadeTechnician.  This seems to return the names of those profiles that have a 'folder2' under folder 1 and puts them into NotOld.txt, regardless of file date within folder2.  No output for Old.txt generated for the folder that does not have folder2.  ty for the push though!

Comment: Ok, I modified it and it should do what you want now.